# Example of a field that is not a monotone class

Tags: measure-theory, monotone-class-theorem

> Example of a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets) that is not a monotone class.

I tried to come up with a field for which the limit would be a singleton but the finite union or complements or intersections wouldn't be that. Define
$$B_n=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x<\frac{1}{n}\right\}$$
Clearly, $B_1\supset B_2\supset B_3...$ and $\cap_{i=1}^nB_i=B_n$ but, $\cap_{i=1}^\infty B_i=\{0\}$, which cannot be expressed as a finite union of any $B_n$'s or their complements. Therefore, the minimal field generated by $\{B_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not a monotone class.

Is the above example valid? Is there an "easier" example (in the sense that it is easier to prove)?

Comment: I've edited the tags; the term "field" is used in (at least) two different ways in math, and the "field-theory" tag is about the one *not* related to your question.

Comment: Unless you meant $B_n = \{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid |x|\lt \frac{1}{n}\}$, your calculations are incorrect, as $\cap B_i = (-\infty,0]$.

Comment: The least field generated by the $B_n$ contains more than just finite unions of the $B_i$ and their complements. For example, it also includes $B_{2}\cap (B_1)^c = [1,2)$, which cannot be expressed as a finite union of any of the $B_n$s or their complements, either.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh right! I meant $|x|$, was visualizing a ball centred at $0$. Also, I understand the field also contains "rings" and their complements and complements of $B_n$'s. However,finite complement/union of none of these combinations can be a singleton $\{0\}$, I think? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the field of all finite or cofinite subsets of a given infinite set.